# Prove that $[0,2)∪\{2 +1/n:n ∈ ℕ\}$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Prove that the set $A$ $=$ $[0,2)$ $∪$ $\{2 +1/n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ with the standard metric is connected.

Assume that $A$ is not connected, meaning that it can be written as the union of two non-empty, disjoint, open sets $U$ and $V$.Since $U$ and $V$ are open, for each point $x ∈ U$, there exists an $ε_x > 0$ such that the ball $B(x, ε_x) = \{y \in A : d(x, y) < ε_x\}$ is contained in $U$. Similarly, for each point $y ∈ V$, there exists an $ε_y > 0$ such that the ball $B(y, ε_y) = \{z \in A : d(y, z) < ε_y\}$ is contained in $V$.

Since $A$ is the union of $[0,2)$ and $\{2 + 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, and $U$ and $V$ are disjoint, we must have that either $[0,2) \subseteq U$ and $\{2 + 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \} \subseteq V$, or vice versa.

NOW HOW TO APPROACH...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A=[0,2) union {2+1/n : n € ℕ}..prove that A is connected

Comment: I can't, since it is not.

Comment: Okay.. please give reason

Comment: No. *You* try to prove it is not. Hint: draw it.

Comment: Okay .. thank you..

Comment: Maybe you were thinking of something like $X = \{0\}\times [0,2]$, $Y=[0,1] \times \{2+\frac{1}{n}\:|\:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $A=X \cup Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A$ is disconneted since $A=\left(A\cap\left(-\infty,\frac{11}4\right)\right)\cup\left(\{3\}\cap\left(\frac{11}4,\infty\right)\right)$, and both $\left(A\cap\left(-\infty,\frac{11}4\right)\right)$ and $\left(\{3\}\cap\left(\frac{11}4,\infty\right)\right)$ are non-empty open disjoint subsets of $A$.

Comment: Better let the OP practice than spoon-feed them.